# Помогите с кнопками в Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

После небольшого курса python я решил сделать свой таймер для программ. Сама она рабочая, но вот я имею трудности с переносом в полноценную программу с GUI. Решил попробовать Kivy, посмотрев видеоролики приступил к разработке. И столкнулся с проблемой кнопок. Я банально не знаю как можно сделать 2 кнопки по разным сторонам, как на макете.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Помогите пожалуйста! И еще я не знаю как можно сделать фон оранжевым, как на картинке. Все просмотрел, но когда вывожу то происходит следующее, либо кнопки вылазят, либо картинка фона, использовал `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается через элементы разметки или макеты, в документациях встречается [под названием layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/layouts.html). Комбинируя разлиные элементы-макеты, вы можете создавать сложные графические интерфейсы. Поэтому вам нужно изучить, что делает тот или иной элемент и научиться их комбинировать. Как правило это приходит с практикой и разбором примеров.

Как сделать фон рассказывается в [гайде по Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html#add-a-color-to-the-background-of-a-custom-layouts-rule-class)

Итак, `GridLayout` позволит разделить пространство на разные части, а `AnchorLayout` привязать кнопки к разным сторонам. Таким образом мы получим нижнюю часть нашего пользовательствого интерфейса.

```
btn_layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
left_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left', anchor_y='bottom')
left_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Left', width=60, height=40, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None))
right_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y='bottom')
right_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Right', width=60, height=40, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None))
btn_layout.add_widget(left_layout)
btn_layout.add_widget(right_layout)
```

Дальше мы можем вложить эту часть в другой макет, который будет уровнем выше.

```
full_layout = GridLayout(rows=2)
full_layout.add_widget(Label(text="MyApp"))
full_layout.add_widget(btn_layout)
```

В итоге получим то, что надо:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        btn_layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        left_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left', anchor_y='bottom')
        left_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Left', width=60, height=40, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None))
        right_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y='bottom')
        right_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Right', width=60, height=40, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None))
        btn_layout.add_widget(left_layout)
        btn_layout.add_widget(right_layout)

        full_layout = GridLayout(rows=2)
        full_layout.add_widget(Label(text="MyApp"))
        full_layout.add_widget(btn_layout)

        return full_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше остается добавить задний фон, через FloatLayout и Canvas по гайду, который указан в начале ответа. Полный код будет выглядеть так:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        btn_layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        left_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left', anchor_y='bottom')
        left_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Left', width=60, height=40, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None))
        right_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y='bottom')
        right_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Right', width=60, height=40, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None))
        btn_layout.add_widget(left_layout)
        btn_layout.add_widget(right_layout)

        full_layout = GridLayout(rows=2)
        full_layout.add_widget(Label(text="MyApp"))
        full_layout.add_widget(btn_layout)

        self.root = root = FloatLayout()
        root.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)

        with root.canvas.before:
            Color(1, 136/255, 0, 1) 
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=root.size, pos=root.pos)

        root.add_widget(full_layout)
        return root

    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = instance.pos
        self.rect.size = instance.size


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С остальным потренируйтесь сами, будет полезнее и руку можно набить. А так же посмотрите и разберите гайд по Widgets, в нем есть много чего интересного и полезного.

Comment: Я попробовал ваш код, вывело ошибку
   full_layout.add_widget(lable(text="MyApp"))
 NameError: name 'lable' is not defined

Comment: Вроде я понимаю в чем проблема, но как ее решить

Comment: Вообщем разберусь сам. Спасибо что ответили!

Comment: @MaksimMusienko нужно подключить пакеты для всех используемых классов, к примеру для Label это будет `from kivy.uix.label import Label` и следить за регистром, в данном случае `Label` с большой буквы (тут вы написали с маленькой, возможно в этом дело). Я не вставил эти импорты, но думаю разберетесь, в документации к каждому классу указано в каком он пакете.

Comment: Аа понял, я просто дурачек не обратил внимание на импорт лейбла